# Animated background in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

I want to animate my background after a view got loaded in my iOS application. This works with  solid colors, but I'm not able to let it work using background images. This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
        self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
        self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_dark.png"]];
    }];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

You animate things like this:

```
view.backgroundColor = INITIAL COLOR
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
    view.backgroundColor = FINAL COLOR
}];
```

The `animate` method animates the change from the current state to whatever you set up in the animation block. The animation block is not a list of steps.

Therefore, I think what you want is this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_dark.png"]];
}];
```

Also, do NOT call `commitAnimations` afterward, that's only if you're using the old-style `beginAnimations` method. Read the documentation, and don't just call methods to see if they work.

Comment: In fact, old-style animations sometimes leak memory for CGContextRef

Comment: In my case I'm trying to change background color multiple times due to user scroll but it only works for first time then it is changing background without animation, what can be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

Not all properties can be animated like this. It is very likely that a background image is one of them. What you can do is have a second view on top with the new image and animate its alpha from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Ty this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
        self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_dark.png"]];
    }];
```